# Android using views' handler to run code

Tags: java, android

I saw that in AOSP there's a lot of code run something like:

```
v.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Here comes code
            x += y;
        }
    });
```

What's the advantage of doing this versus just doing plain `x += y;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This run will get the call when the view attached to the main user interface thread. have a look the post method in [View](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java) class.

```
 /**
     * <p>Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue.
     * The runnable will be run on the user interface thread.</p>
     *
     * @param action The Runnable that will be executed.
     *
     * @return Returns true if the Runnable was successfully placed in to the
     *         message queue.  Returns false on failure, usually because the
     *         looper processing the message queue is exiting.
     *
     * @see #postDelayed
     * @see #removeCallbacks
     */
    public boolean post(Runnable action) {
        final AttachInfo attachInfo = mAttachInfo;
        if (attachInfo != null) {
            return attachInfo.mHandler.post(action);
        }

        // Postpone the runnable until we know on which thread it needs to run.
        // Assume that the runnable will be successfully placed after attach.
        getRunQueue().post(action);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: And if the view isn't attached at that moment of post() the Runnable won't run until it is attached?